# Changing PPAs from lucid to maverick

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a tool to update my PPA sources.list entries after upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42895/is-there-a-tool-to-update-my-ppa-sources-list-entries-after-upgrading)

I recently upgraded to Maverick and I have a not so long list of PPAs. Is there a way to quickly change the distribution from lucid to maverick without using a text editor?

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983/270) question and answers for all the info about PPAs. However the direct answer is as follows:

A PPA is not restricted to a particular release (like lucid, maverick etc). The same ppa normally contains versions for many distributions and this is the preferred way of migrating ppa's over to new distribution releases - where most of the effort is on the ppa owner.

So simply adding back the ppa to your sources list will make the maverick version of updates and new packages from the ppa available immediately to you. Of course, if the maintainer has not released versions for maverick yet, then these won't be available now, but as soon as these are posted they will be picked up "automagically" :-).

If you are not using `add-apt-repository` or providing the apt-line to synaptic (which are both distribution neutral) and are directly editing files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` or in synaptic, take care to replace any occurrence of the word `lucid` with `maverick`

Answer (score 1):

My advice is install ubuntu tweak, this software can do it for you automatically

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is up to the owners of the PPAs to update them to maverick.  I tried reactivating some of my PPAs that were disabled during the update as maverick PPAs, and several of them returned 404 errors, not found.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually check each ppa since some of them hadn't migrated to maverick yet.

that's why ubuntu upgrade procdeure leave them (the ppa sources.list.d entries) unchanged and disabled.