# Would upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10 break bumblebee

Tags: upgrade, bumblebee

Soo would it break my bumblebee, couse it works pretty good now...
Would i have to reinstall it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using 12.10 with bumblebee and it works fine. I reinstalled my system instead of upgrading. I guess you installed bumblebee using the ppa. The ppa will be deactivated during the upgrade process. Take a look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42895/is-there-a-tool-to-update-my-ppa-sources-list-entries-after-upgrading) to see how to re-enable them. After you have done so, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This should update bumblebee to the latest version available for 12.10.