# How can I manage ppa if I only have terminal access through ssh?

Tags: ppa

This would work if I had direct access to the server:
[Is there a tool to update my PPA sources.list entries after upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42895/is-there-a-tool-to-update-my-ppa-sources-list-entries-after-upgrading)

But which are the underlying commands this tool uses?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit `/etc/apt/sources.list`. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine) is a comprehensive guide to it.