# Repository Location

Tags: apt, ppa, repository, synaptic

I've recently updated to a development version of Trusty, and it disabled all the `PPAs` I've added. I have quite a lot of `PPAs`, but when I enable it in Synaptic, it automatically scrolls to the top, so I need to scroll down again just to enable another repo. I've searched around and apparently the repositories are in `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but when I looked there, there are only a few of my added repos there.

Does anyone know where the rest of the PPAs are located. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/42895/is-there-a-tool-to-update-my-ppa-sources-list-entries-after-upgrading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Avatar Parto's comment, and I installed Y-PPA-Manager.

You can install it with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```