# How do I change a PPA from 11.10 to 11.04?

Tags: 11.10, ppa

How do I change Oneiric to Natty in sources list? I want to know this cause Oneiric has a problem with the PPA.

Comment: Very much similar to [Changing PPAs from Lucid to Maverick](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5490/changing-ppas-from-lucid-to-maverick)

Comment: Messing with the software sources will likely break things. Make sure to have a good backup before beginning.

Comment: "Very much similar to Changing PPAs from Lucid to Maverick" this article did not help me for my problem, yes its about the same but it doesn't give me the answers i want

Answer (score 1):

To change your personal PPAs:

- Open `Repositories` and type the administrator password when asked;
- Select the `Other Software` tab;
- Select the PPA you want to edit and hit the `Edit` button;
- In the `Distribution` field, just change the text `oneiric` to `natty`.

Be careful and remember, this operation may break things.

Answer (score 0):

If Oneiric has "a problem" (you did not specify) with the PPA, it is likely that the PPA has not been updated to support Oneiric as yet.